# How to print all jars passed into maven compiler plugin

Tags: java, maven

How do I print all jars passed in as dependencies to maven compiler?

```
-Dmaven.compiler.verbose
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean -Dmaven.compiler.verbose=true ?

Comment: yes. [ignore bloody validation]

Comment: FYI: `-Dmaven.compiler.verbose` is short for `-Dmaven.compiler.verbose=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths will be printed as debug logging by the Maven compiler plugin. Use `-X` to enable debug logging then filter out the specific lines:

```
mvn -X test-compile | fgrep 'classpathElements ='
```

Shows:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [XXX/target/classes]
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [XXX/target/test-classes, XXX/target/classes, YY
Y/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar, YYY/.m2/repository/org/hamcres/h
amcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar]
```

Piping the output through `less` will show more detail around these lines.

Answer (score 1):

`$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`

Example output

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |        \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile
```

Look [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

Comment: That's a good idea. Anyway to print at the time of compile itself?

Comment: @Fakrudeen You could always attach the execution of the dependency plugin to your build lifecycle via your pom as described [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins)